# vue autocomplete input that accepts an array of object

Tags: arrays, vue.js, object, autocomplete

vue autocomplete input that accepts an array of objects and view only one attribute of the object and value will be the id I couldn't found this kind of library or code can you guys help me.

example

```
<template>
  <autocomplete
    :data="arrayOfObject.firstName + ' ' + arrayOfObject.lastName"
    V-Model="selected"
    :value="arrayOfObject.id"
  />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      arrayOfObject: [
        {
          firstName: "example",
          lastName: "example",
          id: "10",
        },
        {
          firstName: "example2",
          lastName: "example2",
          id: "11",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: what is wrong with the output of above codes?

Comment: This is not a fictional code.it is just to briefly explain the question.

Comment: I couldn't find Vue library that can accept an object and make an autocomplet input like that

Comment: normally `V-Model="selected"` will be one object of the Array binds to the data source of the `autocomplete`. if so, `selected.id` will be what you need.

Comment: There is no autocomplete component that can accept this kind of input and make the autocomplete input-field I want the component that generate the auto complete input-field

Comment: Here's one that can work as intented using the `:source` prop: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuejs-auto-complete